# Font-awesome need to be hovered to display

Tags: css, font-face, font-awesome

I can't find reason/eplanation on web why I experience this. I use the typical settings:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I don't know why most of the time the icon appears hollow, but when you hover on it, it automatically appears.

Comment: can we see an example use or is it on all uses?

Comment: i just used it as is: `<i class=" fa fa-caret-right"></i>`

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your CSS. Do you have any live example for us to work with?

Comment: actually it is happening in chrome only. I tested it on different browser and it looks ok. anyway here is the site: http://dev.printexpress.co.jp/ notice on the breadcrumbs' and buttons' icon

Comment: i can see it in chrome (i think newest version of chrome)

Comment: I'm using version 33.0.1750.146

Comment: As am I. Not sure why it'd be different. maybe you just have a bad internet connection?